# mongodb query with $type operator doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I use following document schema:

```
//User Document
 {
     "_id": "0610457c-b25b-4e73-b859-11987a3fe271",
     "FirstName": "Some Name",
     "LastName": "surname",
     // it is array of ledger items
     "LedgerBook": [
            {
                "AccountId": "aadfgdf6319d3-1a12-4575-9776-c6653sdfg5c32527",
                "TransactionId": "ef98bbc4-3efb-46dc-b632-5adfgdfg1fcc378446",
                ....
            },
            ... 
      ]
```

and when I try to apply query `db.users.find({ "LedgerBook" : { "$type" : 4 } }).limit(50);` it returns nothing, but for query `db.users.find({ "LedgerBook" : { "$type" : 3 } }).limit(50);` works well(return all documents that has LedgerBook items).

Why does it happen?

type = 4 is Array and type = 3 is Object.

I want to get all documents thats have at least one LedgerBook item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you query against an array the test is conceptually applied to each element of the array until it returns true for one of the elements, or until the end of the array is reached.

So the query:

```
db.items.find({ LedgerBook : { $type : 4 }})
```

actually means: find all documents where at least one of the items of the LedgerBook array is itself an array. Even though LedgerBook itself is an array, none of its elements are, so no documents match the query.

If you just want to query for documents that have a LedgerBook element you can use:

```
db.items.find({ LedgerBook : { $exists : true }})
```

Comment: First query behaivor looks like strange for me. How i can check type of LedgerBook thats within parent document? Also @Andrei want all documents thats contatains LedgerBook with items count more than 1. But your second query return all documents that contaitns LedgerBook(even if array items count equal 0).

Comment: That's how queries against arrays work. Might seem strange, but most of the time it's exactly what you want. To test for a LedgerBook array with 1 or more entries you'd have to use a $where clause:

Comment: > db.items.find({ $where : function() { return this.LedgerBook instanceof Array && this.LedgerBook.length > 0; }})

Comment: I know that i can do it with `$where`. But i like this solution: `db.users.find( { "LedgerBook.0.AccountId" : { $exists : true } })` ;). In any way thanks for pointing out how `$type` work for array. Also will be great if you will add your answer to the mongodb documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24type). Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The $type of an array is defined through the type of its first item. Call it a bug or a feature. There is some issue posted to JIRA...

Comment: Can you please give link to a bug/feature. It's looks like a bug for me...  In any way thanks for pointing it out. +1

Answer (score 2):

It sound like a bug, i've tried run `{ "Array" : { $type : 4 } }` from mongovue and it's also does not work for me. Going to check in mongoshell...

But if you want to know all nested array with at least one item you can do it like this:

```
db.users.find( { "LedgerBook.0.AccountId" : { $exists : true } })
```

**Update:** Following code also return nothing in mongoshell, so i guess it's bug..

```
db.items.find( { "Array" : { $type : 4 } })
```